# How to support signs like hyphen, question mark and semi colon in my post url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

In my php website. I have a file called viewPost.php
This shows the post. The problem I'm facing is whenever there is a sign like ( ?, :, &, ;) etc used as post title, the post will return error when opened. I want the url to rewrite and make the link neat.

My viewPost.php looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');

require "core/functions.php";

$post_id = $_GET['id'];

$post = get_post($_GET['id'], str_replace("-", " ", $_GET['title']));
$title  =  ucfirst($post[0]['post_title']) ?? "Newsdesk";
require "template/header.php";

?>


<div class="uk-container uk-container-small post-content">
    <?php if ($post) { ?>

        <div class="uk-margin-large-top">
            <h1> <?= ucfirst( $post[0]['post_title'] ) ?> </h1>
            <div class="post-meta uk-margin">
                <span class="date uk-text-bold">Posted On: <?= date("M j Y @ g:i a", strtotime($post[0]['date_created'])) ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <?= $post[0]['post_content'] ?>
            </div>

            <div class="share uk-padding uk-background-muted uk-margin">
                <h3>Share This</h3>
                <div class="shre-icons" id="shareBlock">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php }  ?>
```

While my .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^post/?$ allPost.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ viewPost.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^post/video/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ viewVideo.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
```

for instance, if there's a ? in post title, the link is rendered like http://example.com/post/11/Is-jack-a-boy?

This affects the article from being read.

Comment: The `?` has special meaning in a URL, it starts the query string. You should not use it for other purposes. If you need to use it as part of a slug - then it should be properly URL-encoded. But even then it can easily become problematic again, if a user tried to request your URL directly via their address bar. It is really best if you refrain from using any characters with such special meaning to begin with in your post slugs.

Comment: Ok thanks @CBroe . There are some websites that use a lot of ??? in their post title and when the url is opened it doesnt show that ? again in the url link. I'm wondering how they do that.

Comment: Most sites have functions to "translate" a title into a slug in place, that do things exactly like this, replace problematic characters. WordPress f.e. has https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title/